# Best approach for accessing activities from another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, layout

I'm developing a simple home launcher. Main activity is the home layout, in it there is a button to call another activity to show the apps list. In this second activity, if you long press an icon, it adds to home screen.
So, from the second activity (apps list) I add an imageview to the main activity (home screen), but to do this I need to get the main layout, which it's not possible from different activity than itself.

To achieve this, I'm thinking different options like this:

1-Declaring a variable in the second activity:

```
public static RelativeLayout mainLayout;
```

Set it in the first:

```
// MainActivity
Intent i = new Intent(this, DrawerActivity.class);
DrawerActivity.mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
startActivity(i);
```

2-Using fragments avoiding the jumps between activities.

3-Changing the layout in the main activity (one activity for two layouts).

4-Declaring class descending from Application and store here everything I need in the different activities.

5-Use of broadcasters.

The question is: which is the right approach to achieve this ?
I've read several docs but there is no clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't go with option 1. That's the best way to leak memory and context, and you don't want that. Resources associated with an Activity (in this case the layout) should be private to that Activity. This ensures that the framework can manage memory as it was designed to.

To communicate between activities, the official way is to pass parameters in the [intent](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html) that launches the activity. You can add the identifier of the application you want to add to the main screen, and than retrieve the image either from the intent (as seen in the link) or if second Activity is launched for a result, then in the [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method of your home Activity.

However in you case I would suggest another approach. As you have to persist the layout of the home screen, I would create a database table containing the positions of the applications added to the main screen. I would modify the database entries where it's convenient and rebuild the main screen's layout every time it is displayed based on the database.

Comment: That's a good approach, but it's not fully what I want/like. In Delphi/Lazarus you can access all forms from wherever you want, why can't do the same in Android?

Comment: Android is a managed environment, the platform makes no guaranties that any resource allocated in an Activity will be accessible once that Activity gets off the screen. It's a mobile operating system that should be responsive under any circumstances, that requires some sacrifices.

Comment: I recommend starting with the basics, Android is not desktop or web, even different from other mobile platforms. You have to change your mindset to create applications. You should not violate the platform just to develop in the way you used to, it might work in most of the cases, but in the cases it won't it'll be really hard to reproduce errors and fix them.